# Transform SQL LIMIT query to Dynamodb

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

How can I transform this sql query `Select name , college_id,phone_number from users where college_id =2 limit 100` in `dyanmodb`.

I tried below code

```
  $iterator = $dynamo->query(array(
                    'TableName'     => 'users',
                    'IndexName' => 'college_id-phone_number-index',
                    'ScanIndexForward' => false,
                    'KeyConditions' => array(
                        'college_id' => array(
                            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                                array('S' => (string)$collegeId )
                            ),
                            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
                        ),
                        'phone_number' => array(
                            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                                array('S' => (string)$phoneNumber)
                            ),
                            'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ'
                        )

                    ),

                    **'Limit' => 100,**
                )

            );
```

I found that `Limit = 100` restrict the **total number of items to process** than **total number of matching items to return** .

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There is no equivalent to the SQL `LIMIT` command in Amazon DynamoDB. You should keep iterating through the paged result sets until you have reached the desired number of records.</strike>

**Update:**

Oops! There *is* a limit parameter. From [`QUERY` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query_v20111205.html):

> **Limit:** The maximum number of items to return (not necessarily the number of matching items). If DynamoDB processes the number of items up to the limit while querying the table, it stops the query and returns the matching values up to that point, and a *LastEvaluatedKey* to apply in a subsequent operation to continue the query. Also, if the result set size exceeds 1MB before DynamoDB hits this limit, it stops the query and returns the matching values, and a *LastEvaluatedKey* to apply in a subsequent operation to continue the query.

So, keep paging through 1MB result sets until the limit is met.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. is sql LIMIT is not available even in latest SDKs ? Asking this to confirm so that i stop searching for this feature and implement my own logic ....